# Xamarin forms HTTPS data request not work on android

Tags: json, api, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I recently downloaded **Visual Studio 2017**, on Xamarin I start a new proyect, everything goes Ok, when I try to **consume REST Api service**, the app dont do the request, **I install my nugets on all my proyect in this order**: 
**1. Microsoft build
2. Micrososft.net.http
3. Newtonjson**
***the app only do the request on UWP app, not in Android app, not in IOS App***, Im kind of tired to find this error, I need help
here's the link I took for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xNP-K37mssA&t=785s in in spanish by the way.

```
 ---- JSON OBJECT CLASS--
    namespace App1
    {
        public class WingetResult
        {
            public int userId { get; set; }
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string title { get; set; }
            public string body { get; set; }
        }
    }

    -----Generic get request-----
    namespace App1
    {
        public class RestClient
        {
            //Metodo generico para cualquier peticion tipo get
            public async Task<T> Get<T>(string url)
            {
                try
                {
                    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                    var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
                    if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("else HTTP CLIENT STATUS no es OK");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
                return default(T);
            }
        }
    }

    ----MAIN PAGE CODE------
    namespace App1
    {

        public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
        {

            public MainPage()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            protected override void OnAppearing()
            {
                base.OnAppearing();
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {

                    RestClient client = new RestClient();
                    var wingetResult = await client.Get<WingetResult>("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1");
                    if (wingetResult != null)
                    {
                        label1.Text = wingetResult.title;
                    }
                    else {
                        label1.Text = "no";
                    }


                });

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post your code for consume rest calls...

Comment: class jsonobject    

public class WingetResult
    {
        public int userId { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string body { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Edit the question with sample code...

Comment: okok, I don't know if it's the code or the visual studio nuget package

Comment: Is this true  >  if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)  ???

Comment: When I taste it on my Android app isn't true, but in UWP app it goes true...

Comment: All test on Simulator?

Comment: I just run it using my phone... it goes wrong

Comment: follow the code that i publish

Comment: @SilverQui. You should use the native `HttpClientHandler` that Xamarin supplies... : https://blog.xamarin.com/securing-web-requests-with-tls-1-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with the HTTPS request

i will suggest you to use [ModernHttpClient](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/modernhttpclient)

Comment: the problem is not the plugin, the problem is that my app works only on UWP not in Android or IOS

Comment: oh sorry, i didn't notice, yes my permissions are correct in android

Comment: permissions on my android manifest are checked
INTERNET and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

Comment: how do i check it? my run time gaves me this :
on my try catch

Comment: Error at System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request ---> System.Net.WebException: Error: SecureChannelFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.) ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The authentication or decryption has failed.

Comment: I just saw your URL, its HTTPS... check my solution here

Comment: I go to that conclusion too, I tried and I will give you my answer

Comment: Shloud I use it instead of Microsoft.net.http or use it with?

Comment: ok, I just add library and change my 

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

to

 var client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());
                var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

Comment: @ShiwankaChathuranga You should use the native `HttpClientHandler` that Xamarin supplies... : https://blog.xamarin.com/securing-web-requests-with-tls-1-2/